# What´s wrong with my for-loop?

Tags: c, arrays

I´ve two for loops. In the first loop i split the field(division).
In the second loop i wanna printf the new field values.
There are only 0´s.
I wanna know what´s wrong with the loops. 
I don´t find a mistake. :))
I think the problem is in this Line:

```
purverbrauch[i] = wertmverbrauch[i]/summe;
```

I program with Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 7.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define N 7

int main()
{
int wertmverbrauch[N], summe=0, tmp, purverbrauch[N];
int i, j, y;
printf("Programm zur Ermittlung des kumulierten wertmaeßigen       Verbrauchs\n-----------------------------------------\n");
printf("Bitte geben Sie den wertm. Verbrauch ein!(%i Werte)",N);
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    scanf_s("%i", &wertmverbrauch[i]);//Einlesen der Werte
}
for (j = 0; j < N - 1; j++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < N - 1 - j; y++)
    {
        if (wertmverbrauch[y]>wertmverbrauch[y + 1])//Bubblesort sortieren
        {
            tmp = wertmverbrauch[y];
            wertmverbrauch[y] = wertmverbrauch[y + 1];
            wertmverbrauch[y + 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

printf("Sortierte Reihenfolge(nach wert absteigend)");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf("\n%i", wertmverbrauch[i]);//Sortierte Ganzzahlen-Werte ausgeben
}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    summe += wertmverbrauch[i];//Ermittlung der Summe in Ganzzahlen
}
printf("\nDie Werte ergeben zusammen %i\n\n", summe);
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    purverbrauch[i] = wertmverbrauch[i]/summe;
}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf("%i\n", purverbrauch[i]);
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

%lf output(correct):

```
Programm zur Ermittlung des kumulierten wertmae▀igen Verbrauchs
-----------------------------------------
Bitte geben Sie den wertm. Verbrauch ein!(4 Werte)5
4
1
4
Sortierte Reihenfolge(nach wert absteigend)
1.000000

4.000000

4.000000

5.000000

Die Werte ergeben zusammen 14.000000

0.071429
0.285714
0.285714
0.357143
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

%f output(incorrect):

```
Programm zur Ermittlung des kumulierten wertmae▀igen Verbrauchs
-----------------------------------------
Bitte geben Sie den wertm. Verbrauch ein!(4 Werte)5
4
1
4
Sortierte Reihenfolge(nach wert absteigend)
-92559604497122535000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

-92559604473177292000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

-92559604473177292000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

-92559604281615349000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

Die Werte ergeben zusammen -3702384177250924700000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000.000000

0.250000
0.250000
0.250000
0.250000
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Comment: What is the value of `summe` ?

Comment: Show more code, especially the types of your arrays.

Comment: @haccks int initialized with value 0.

Comment: `What´s wrong with my for-loop?` -- Trying to _guess_.

Comment: ... and did you debug the program ? Debugging with Visual Studio 2013 is not especially difficult.

Comment: Why do you think there's anything wrong with the for loops? Did you get any error?

Comment: if `wertmverbrauch` is array of ints integer division will take place, if `summe` is greater than any of `wertmverbrauch` elements integer division will result zeros.

Comment: %d is equivalent to %i (at least in my man page)

Comment: Are you struggling with integer division??

Comment: @jsantander i add the full code now.

Comment: Dude, dividing by 0. There has to be something wrong with it.

Comment: @Kraken pls look my full code. There i calculated Summe . Its german but pls forgive me ;)

Comment: Decide which *language* you are programming in. The answer to *this* question would probably be the same for both tagged languages but it's a good idea nevertheless.

Comment: I edited it leaving `c` only, because of `scanfs`, and `stdlib.h`. I don't think I see any c++ specific feature, and a fact that c++ compilers will (or at least should) compile any c code is not a valid reason to tag for both.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the problem is that your array is of type int, so basically you get results between 0 and 1, but integers are 0 if they are smaller than one.

```
int N = 4
double purverbrauch[N];
double wertmverbrauch[N] = {2,3,4,5};
int summe = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
purverbrauch[i] = wertmverbrauch[i]/summe;
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf("%f\n", purverbrauch[i]);
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer. but why you initialized the array wertemverbrauch with 2,3,4,5 ? :D

Comment: if you declare the array just as I did above, you should be fine. But you can use `float` too, if you do not need the precision for calculations. `%f` prints a float, so the double is casted into a float anyway.

Comment: @user3337177 Theolodis did not want to scanf the array wertemverbrauch. Hence some random values `2,3,4,5` are used.

Comment: @user3337177 instead of `int wertmverbrauch[N], summe=0, tmp, purverbrauch[N];` go for `int summe=0, tmp;` and `float wertmverbrauch[N], purverbrauch[N];` with `scanf_s("%f", ...)`

Comment: @user3337177 Can you give us the output you are getting when you use %f and when you use %lf? Thanks

Comment: @user3337177 sorry, scanf_s is windows specific, so I am not sure, but if `%lf` works I guess that your problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have declared only integers.

In integer math, `10 / 3` is ***not*** `3.3333` (as you might expect); it is only `3` (an integer).

I suspect that the values you divide would result in values less than 1, and as a result, the result is integer 0.

Example:

You might expect:

```
3 / 5 = 0.60
```

But really:

```
3 / 5 = 0
```

---

The proper solution is to examine your data, and change appropriate types to be `double`, instead of `int`.  Then you can capture decimal places.

Comment: thx for your answer. can i declare the array as double? (formatted with %f)?

Comment: Right now you'll be getting all zeroes right? If the code uses `int`

Answer (score 0):

You need floting point calculations here and not integer calculations.

Replace

```
int wertmverbrauch[N], summe=0, tmp, purverbrauch[N];
```

by

```
double wertmverbrauch[N], summe=0, tmp, purverbrauch[N];
```

and replace all occurences of `%i` by `%lf`.